# How to add a jpg or png image to an UIImage and then display in a UIImageView?

Tags: image, uiimageview, uiimage

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"contactHeader.png"];
_headersView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

I have already hooked up the connections for the UIImageView (_headersView) in IB. The image I want to load is in my project tree structure as well.

Am I creating the UIImage the right way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the file is in your bundle you can just use

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contactHeader"];
_headersView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

If the image is in your documents directory you can use

```
// Get the path to your documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Add the file to the end of the documents path
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contactHeader.png"];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
_headersView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
[img release]; img = nil;
```

Comment: By bundle you mean project tree right? If yes, then I already have those two lines exactly like that, but still no image shows. What else should I check?

Comment: Sorry if you made the `UIImageView` in `IB` then you do not `... alloc] init` as it was created for you by `IB` so just set `_headerView.image = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
-(NSString *)getPath:(NSString *)filename
{
self.path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:filename ofType:@"png"];
return path;
path = nil;
}

self.youImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self getPath:@"123"]];
```